# NativeScript Angular ListPicker that behaves like `<select>`

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

By default the [ListPicker](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listpicker) takes up a ton of screen space.  Is there a way to make it behave like the metaphor for the HTML `<select>` when shown on mobile?

I've used [this react native plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) before, and its exactly the metaphor I want, but for NativeScript.

Is this easy to do via NativeScript?  I want to make use of the platform specific select metaphors, so showing/hiding a `ListPicker` or putting `ListPicker` in a modal is not what I'm looking for.

Also, I'm going to have a fairly long list, so an [action Dialog](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/dialogs) wont work for me.

**Update**: I'm aware of [nativescript-drop-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down), however it does not use the platform specific "choose from list of choices" widget that webviews and [react native plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) do.

By "platform specific choose from list of choices widget" I mean this (from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select):

**iOS** (note picker renders where keyboard would, with rolodex picker):

[image]

**Android** (note modal, with scroll list of options):

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how `ListPicker` in a modal is not what you want, when the RN plugin you highlight as exactly what you want is essentially a `ListPicker` in a modal?

Comment: yup, update made with screenshots.  I don't know why its not letting me shrink img sizes to a thumbnail per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [nativescript-drop-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down) which is similar to the react-native-picker-select you had pointed.

Comment: I saw that, but its not using the platform specific selectors.  I'll update my q to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution and couldn't find one so I have created my own. I have attached a sample for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ruE3Qf&v=2).

You can have a textField/Label and onTab you can show the ListPicker, like `Select` behaves in HTML and it will use the native(platform specific) components only.

in your HTML

```html
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="210" height="210" backgroundColor="lightgray">
  <Label text="Country" width="70" height="50" backgroundColor="red"></Label>
  <TextField [(ngModel)]="textFieldValue" hint="Choose countty..." editable="false" (tap)="showHideField('country')"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="100%" height="210" *ngIf="showCountryPicker" backgroundColor="lightgray">
  <ListPicker [items]="listPickerCountries" (selectedIndexChange)="selectedCountyChanged($event)"></ListPicker>
</StackLayout>
```

and your .ts file

```js
showCountryPicker = false;
listPickerCountries: Array < string > = ["Australia", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Canada", "Switzerland",
  "China", "Czech Republic", "Germany", "Spain", "Ethiopia", "Croatia", "Hungary",
  "Italy", "Jamaica", "Romania", "Russia", "United States"
];

showHideField() {
  this.showCountryPicker = true;
}
selectedCountyChanged(args) {
  const picker = < ListPicker > args.object;
  this.showCountryPicker = false;
  this.textFieldValue = this.listPickerCountries[picker.selectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  While this method is definitely functional, it still uses `<ListPicker>` under the covers.  Was hoping there was an easy way to leverage the native platform-specific widgets.  I think emulation (like nativescript-drop-down) is currently the only option.

Comment: I tried it on NativeScript Playground and got the following error on Android:  

An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Calling js method onValueChange failed
TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateSelectedValue' of null
   

It did work on iOS.
What is causing this error?